# Do Bernoulli bandits need a different treatment if the rewards are sparse?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits, decision-theory

I have a problem where, effectively, my slot machines have very low payout probability (on the order of 1% for the "best" slot machines) and my goal is to minimize the number of actions to get one reward. I'm wondering if my goal is still equivalent to maximizing long term reward (as in the original formulation). At a higher level, I'm wondering which of the available tools for solving Bernoulli bandit are best to use in my scenario, or even if an altogether different approach would be more appropriate.